# calling a javascript program for a website

Tags: javascript

Html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    start();
</script>
</head>

<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Java script

```
var points = 1;
var points1;
var DELAY = 30;
var SPEED = 5;
var MAX_DY = 12;

var OBSTACLE_WIDTH = 30;
var OBSTACLE_HEIGHT = 100;

var TERRAIN_WIDTH = 10;
var MIN_TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 20;
var MAX_TERRAIN_HEIGHT = 50;

var POINTS_PER_ROUND = 5;

var DUST_RADIUS = 3;
var DUST_BUFFER = 10;

var NUM_OBSTACLES = 3;

var copter;
var dy = 0;
var clicking = false;

var score;  // text you see on the screen

var obstacles = [];
var top_terrain = [];
var bottom_terrain = [];
var dust = [];

function start(){
    starta();
}


function starta() {
    setup();
    setTimer(game, DELAY);
    mouseDownMethod(onMouseDown);
    mouseUpMethod(onMouseUp);
    setTimer(points2, 10)
}


function points2(){
    points1 = points/100
    return points1;
}

function setup() {
    setBackgroundColor(Color.black);
    copter = new WebImage("image.png");
    copter.setSize(25, 50);
    copter.setPosition(getWidth()/3, getHeight()/2);
    copter.setColor(Color.blue);
    add(copter);

    addObstacles();
    addTerrain();

    score = new Text("0");
    score.setColor(Color.white);
    score.setPosition(10, 30);
    add(score);
}

function updateScore() {
    points += POINTS_PER_ROUND;
    score.setText(points);
}

function game() {
    updateScore();
    if (hitWall()) {
        lose();
        return;
    }
    var collider = getCollider();
    if (collider != null) {
        if (collider != copter) {
            lose();
            return;
        }
    }
    if (clicking) {
        dy -= 1;
        if (dy < -MAX_DY) {
            dy = -MAX_DY;
        }
    } else {
        dy += 1;
        if (dy > MAX_DY) {
            dy = MAX_DY;
        }
    }
    copter.move(0, dy);
    moveObstacles();
    moveTerrain();
    moveDust();
    addDust();
}

function onMouseDown(e) {
    clicking = true;
}

function onMouseUp(e) {
    clicking = false;
}

function addObstacles() {
    for (var i = 0; i < NUM_OBSTACLES; i++) {
        var obstacle = new WebImage("image.jpg");
        obstacle.setSize(50, 100);
        obstacle.setColor(Color.green);
        obstacle.setPosition(getWidth() + i * (getWidth()/NUM_OBSTACLES),
                            Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - OBSTACLE_HEIGHT));
        obstacles.push(obstacle);
        add(obstacle);
    }
}

function moveObstacles() {
    for (var i=0; i < obstacles.length; i++) {
        var obstacle = obstacles[i];
        obstacle.move(-points1, 0);
        if(obstacle.getX() < 0) {
            obstacle.setPosition(getWidth(),
                            Randomizer.nextInt(0, getHeight() - OBSTACLE_HEIGHT));
        }
    }
}


function hitWall() {
    var hit_top = copter.getY() < 0;
    var hit_bottom = copter.getY() + copter.getHeight() > getHeight();
    return hit_top || hit_bottom;
}


function lose() {
    stopTimer(game);
    var text = new Text("You Lose!");
    text.setColor(Color.red);
    text.setPosition(getWidth()/2 - text.getWidth()/2,
                     getHeight()/2);
    add(text);

}



function getCollider() {
    var topLeft = getElementAt(copter.getX()-1, copter.getY()-1);
    if (topLeft != null) {
        return topLeft;
    }

    var topRight = getElementAt(copter.getX() + copter.getWidth() + 1,
                                copter.getY() - 1);
    if (topRight != null) {
        return topRight;
    }

    var bottomLeft = getElementAt(copter.getX()-1, 
                                  copter.getY() + copter.getHeight() + 1);
    if (bottomLeft != null) {
        return bottomLeft;
    }

    var bottomRight = getElementAt(copter.getX() + copter.getWidth() + 1,
                                    copter.getY() + copter.getHeight() + 1);
    if (bottomRight != null) {
        return bottomRight;
    }

    return null;
}


function addTerrain() {
    for (var i=0; i <= getWidth() / TERRAIN_WIDTH; i++) {
        var height = Randomizer.nextInt(MIN_TERRAIN_HEIGHT, MAX_TERRAIN_HEIGHT);
        var terrain = new Rectangle(TERRAIN_WIDTH, height);
        terrain.setPosition(TERRAIN_WIDTH * i, 0);
        terrain.setColor(Color.green);
        top_terrain.push(terrain);
        add(terrain);

        height = Randomizer.nextInt(MIN_TERRAIN_HEIGHT, MAX_TERRAIN_HEIGHT);
        var bottomTerrain = new Rectangle(TERRAIN_WIDTH, height);
        bottomTerrain.setPosition(TERRAIN_WIDTH * i, 
                                  getHeight() - bottomTerrain.getHeight());
        bottomTerrain.setColor(Color.green);
        bottom_terrain.push(bottomTerrain);
        add(bottomTerrain);
    }
}


function moveTerrain() {
    for (var i=0; i < top_terrain.length; i++) {
        var obj = top_terrain[i];
        obj.move(-points1, 0);
        if (obj.getX() < -obj.getWidth()) {
            obj.setPosition(getWidth(), 0);
        }
    }

    for (var i=0; i < bottom_terrain.length; i++) {
        var obj = bottom_terrain[i];
        obj.move(-points1, 0);
        if (obj.getX() < -obj.getWidth()) {
            obj.setPosition(getWidth(), getHeight() - obj.getHeight());
        }
    }
}


function addDust() {
    var d = new Circle(DUST_RADIUS);
    d.setColor("#ffd700");
    d.setPosition(copter.getX() - d.getWidth(),
                  copter.getY() + DUST_BUFFER);
    dust.push(d);
    add(d);

}

function moveDust() {
    for (var i=0; i < dust.length; i++) {
        var d = dust[i];
        d.move(-points1, 0);
        d.setRadius(d.getRadius() - 0.1);
        if(d.getX() < 0) {
            remove(d);
            dust.remove(i);
            i--;
        }
    }
}
```

Okay so here is my script. The script works perfectly fine on a codehs sandbox, but now that I want to set it on my own website it is not working. Could some one please help me out. Thank you.

Could some one please tell me how I would execute this code from test.js. Thank you.

Comment: Is it you who wrote this?

Comment: `->` http://quirksmode.org/js/placejs.html `<-`

Comment: Yes it is me who wrote this. We were taken through a step by step tutorial by our teacher. We then modified the code to our own liking. *We were given the bare basics. And our next job is to get it working on a private website which is password protected.

Comment: @reidjako: I asked because it's weird that a person who *can* implement that from the scratch (it's slightly different from copy-pasting from tutorial) cannot google how to include js scripts on a page.

Comment: @zerkms: No the thing is I did google it. And yet all the solutions did not work. Thats why I came here. By the way there was no copy and pasting involved. We were shown how to do each thing, but then we had to figure it out and do it on our own.

Comment: Your script lacks some parts. For example: where `Circle` is defined? "but then we had to figure it out and do it on our own" --- then it shouldn't be a problem - use `<script>` as it's advised in the only answer and here you go.

Comment: Well go to the website codehs, and go into sandbox. The code I posted is what I had in the sandbox, and it worked perfectly. So if I am missing something in the js what is it. Thank you. @zerkms

Comment: @reidjako: as I said - where `Circle` is defined? Where `Randomizer` is defined? Where `Color` is defined?

Comment: @zerkms     var d = new Circle(DUST_RADIUS); Isn't that defining it, the circle is being defined as d? Or is my code jquery rather, javascript?

Comment: @reidjako: nope, it's using it. It must be defined somewhere. It was probably wasn't a good idea to start learning js from such a complex task.

Comment: @zerkms I have done many other tasks, over 200. I thought I understood it pretty well. Would you be able to direct me somewhere to learn about this please. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [learning how to](http://www.creativebloq.com/javascript/javascript-debugging-beginners-3122820) [**debug** JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/javascript-debugging) helps you to find the problem.

Comment: @reidjako: it's pretty curious that after finishing that many tasks you don't understand what definition of `Circle` is.

Comment: @zerkms, a circle is a round object... Ahahahahah. You are really confusing me. codehs.com If you go there and would like to complete that feel free. I did all the exercises from that. Then did more as a class with my teacher. So I am sorry that I am trying to learn.

Comment: @reidjako: I understand what a circle is. I don't see where it's defined. There is no built in constructor with name `Circle` in js. So it must be defined by you somewhere.

Comment: @zerkms: is this what you mean, I am really confused sorry var circle = new jsGraphics(document.getElementById("canvas"));

Comment: @reidjako: nope it's not. Anyway, good luck. PS: I **seriously** advice you to start learning js from the very beginning again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the .js to your HTML page, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/test.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    start(); //starts your program
</script>
```

Comment: The index file still remains black. Note I am not hosting this website it is just off my desktop.

Comment: Have you at least created a full HTML page (not only pasted the js inclusion code in a blank page) ?

Comment: Yes i have, But still no luck. That should be in the head right?

Comment: It doesn't have that much importance. Don't your JS code need any other JS before its inclusion ?

Comment: You need to have the existence of the "image.png" (look at your setup() function).

Comment: I do, @Venom, so that isn't the issue

Comment: That is weird. Do you also have "image.jpg" from addObstacles() ? The issue can be from your browser as well, does the javascript is activated ?

Comment: in my code it is a link to a website, I just removed that link as it is a private photo, of class mates.

Comment: Your JS code is either incomplete or not working from start. I tested it myself, and there are a lot of bugs: Color is not defined, setBackgroundColor is not defined, WebImage is not defined, etc.